# Error when alloc a NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a viewController with a NSFetchedResultsController inside to display some given entity,
since I have several entities to display in different time,
so i try to reuse the viewController,
the first entity works fine,
but when i come the the second entity,
it throws me an error like this:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 1'

and the error occurs here:

NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                       initWithFetchRequest:request
                                       managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                         sectionNameKeyPath:sectionKey
                                              cacheName:entityName];

when the "entityName" is the first entity's name (which is "**Account**") i tried, it works well,
but when it comes to the second entity(which the name is "**Budget**"),it crashed.
can anyone help me out of this?
I'm really confused.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it did not find anything (returning `nil`) and you tried putting this into a  `NSMutableArray` somewhere in your table view's `datasource` methods?

Check if the query with `Budget` returns anything.

If you suspect that the `cacheName` is the culprit (although I don't think so), try setting it to `nil` to check.

Comment: Yes! I've deleted all Account Entity (which worked fine before) and the same problem comes to Account! So I learned that it's very likely that the NSFetchedRusltsController found not thing in the entity and it crashed, but it's not about cache because i tried to set it nil and the problem still remains. Could you please help me to get over it? Because at the very first the Entity Account works fine even there's no managedObjects for it,and it's supposed to work fine even it found nothing and just to display an empty list. So where exactly can the problem be? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: hi Mundi, I've solved the problem, it did occur in the table data source methods. Thanks again for your instruction!